# The declared package "" does not match the expected package src : Atom Editor (Error)

Tags: java, atom-editor

I want to be able to write/compile standalone java files in a random directory (i.e, that doesn't belong to a project). The specific directory `E:/Workspace/Code` has been added as `PATH` or whatever, somewhere. How do I check it? Now I need to undo it as it is affecting my `Atom Editor`. I don't  want to maintain these java files into a Project (so I'm not willing to use IDE's such as Eclipse etc). I need a solution to create and compile standalone java files/programs

I created Java file in `E:/Workspace/Code` and it throws this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOwec.png) (this is the link to image showing the error)

But when I created a Java file in `E:/Workspace/Java` no error was seen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ3lz.png) (this is the link to image where no error is seen)

The error seems pretty simple but I'm unable to configure where that `PATH` has been added! Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: The `package` statement at the top of every Java source code file has to match the directory structure in which it is located.  If you are just starting out, you could consider using IntelliJ or Eclipse, which can help with creating new source code files, instead of using Atom.

Comment: No, I have worked with Java a lot ! I have used IDE's such as Eclipse too. Now what I want is to create `Standalone` java files and be able to compile them. I don't want to maintain a project consisting of `src` folder/package etc!

Comment: If you have created a `java` file in `E:\Workspace\Code` then try compiling it by `cd`-ing into that directory. Also make sure there is not package statement in your code. You should be able to compile standalone files in this manner.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to compile through `cmd` and create `.class` files but my `javac-linter` in `Atom Editor` throws this error and that too only in `E:/Workspace/Code` and not other directories!